# Rx queue implementation and Dispatcher's buffer

Tags: system.reactive

I want to implement a queue which is capable of taking events/items from multiple producers in multiple threads, and consume them all on single thread.
this queue will work in some critical environment, so I am quite concerned with it's stability.

I have implemented it using Rx capabilities, but I have 2 questions:

1. Is this implementation OK? Or maybe it is flawed in some way I do not know of? (as an alternative - manual implementation with Queue and locks)
2. What is Dispatcher's buffer length? Can it handle 100k of queued items?

The code below illustrates my approach, using a simple TestMethod. It's output shows that all values are put in from different threads, but are processed on another single thread.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void RxTest()
{
    Subject<string> queue = new Subject<string>();

    queue
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Subscribe(s =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Observed on ThreadId: {1}", s, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                        },
                    () => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown());

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                queue.OnNext(string.Format("value: {0}, from thread: {1}", i.ToString(), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            }
            queue.OnCompleted();
        });
    }


    Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `EventLoopScheduler`. It's built-in to RX and I think it does everything you want.

You can take any number of observables, call `.ObserveOn(els)` (`els` is your instance of an `EventLoopScheduler`) and you're now marshalling multiple observable from multiple threads onto a single thread and queuing each call to `OnNext` serially.

Comment: EventLoopScheduler might be my choice, but is it possible to "run" that scheduler on current thread? In Dispatcher's Run's blocking manner?

Comment: @deafsheep EventLoopScheduler serially executes the work on different threads for each item. The CurrentThreadScheduler executes code on the  current Thread (which is automatically serial because one thread can only do one thing at a time). It also generates deadlock situations faster than you can type if you use it wrong. For the situation you described, vanilla EventLoopScheduler is probably the way to go.

Comment: @AndersonImes - The `EventLoopScheduler` only uses a new thread if there are no pending items. If there are a number queued up it continues to use the same thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity ah you are right, that's an important distinction. It looks like it does an `EnsureThread()` on a new Schedule call and a `this.thread = null` when the queue is empty. Regardless, yours is still probably the right recommendation. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the behaviour of `Subject` in heavily multithreaded scenarios. I can imagine though that something like `BlockingCollection` (and its underlying `ConcurrentQueue`) are well worn in the situations you're talking about. And simple to boot.

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<long>();

// subscribing
queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()
     .ToObservable(Scheduler.NewThread)
     .Subscribe(i => Debug.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Observed on ThreadId: {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

// sending
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), Scheduler.ThreadPool)
          .Do(i => Debug.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Sent on ThreadId: {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
          .Subscribe(i => queue.Add(i));
```

You certainly don't want to touch queues and locks. The `ConcurrentQueue` implementation is excellent and will certainly handle the size queues you're talking about effectively.

Comment: Thank you very much, your example is very nice and does work exactly as I need without messing with Dispatcher.

Comment: Although, I think there is a problem in your implementation - what if this queue work for a month live? It will store all the items in it right? Meaning it will consume multitudes on memory to hold that all?

Comment: @deafsheep items are getting drained from the queue, so no it won't store them all unless they are not getting consumed, which is the behaviour you want.

Comment: @yamen so if I were to add another consumer, I would have to get another consuming enumerable and change it to observable, right? And to remove the consumer I just dispose the subscription?